# How to show element based on total page number

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.2.Final, my goal is create a pdf with JasperReports. If the total page number greater than 1, then specified content ***SEE ATTACHMENT*** should be displayed on first page, the sample looks like:

```
<columnFooter>
    <band height="207">
        <textField evaluationTime="Report">
            <reportElement x="20" y="25" width="100" height="30" >
                <printWhenExpression>
                    <![CDATA[$V{PAGE_COUNT}.intValue()>1]]>
                </printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["***SEE ATTACHMENT****"]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</columnFooter>
```

But it doesn't work.

Why? is it `$V{PAGE_COUNT}` is not greater than 1 when evaluate the first page?

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Did you try to change the evaluationTime?

Comment: @AlexK change to which? I tried now and report, but they didn't work

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

1. add a text field
2. its expression = $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()>1?"SEE ATTACHMENT":""
3. evaluation time=Report
4. leave Print When Expression empty

For $V{PAGE_COUNT}, no matter which evaluation time, it doesn't mean total page number.

If Print When Expression is : $V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()>1, the $V{PAGE_NUMBER} is 1 when evaluate it on first page, so it cannot solve my problem.